# Kernel Panic with every Linux Distro on my MacBook

Tags: linux, installation, macbook, kernel

I recently bought a 2018 MacBook Pro for iOS development and I'm trying to install Mint/Ubuntu/Debian in a second partition I made before.
The problem is that I keep getting the same error every time I try to run Linux from the USB (I used 3 different USB drives). It doesn't matter which option I choose (live, install or other). After some seconds the screen turns black and it shows many errors like these:

```
-ACPI Exception: AE_NO_MEMORY and Method parse/execution failed
-BUG: stack guarde page was hit at ...
-ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 34
-kernel stack overflow
-Firmware Bug: Page fault caused by Firmware at PA: 0xF0000...
```

The last row also says:

```
Kernel panic- not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

or

```
Kernel panic- not syncing: stack protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: get_cert_list...
```

I searched many times on Google but it brings me only to bug pages with useless info to solve my problem.
Do you think I'll be able to install Linux in some ways? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: See this page>>>>>>>>https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-install-linux-on-mac-3637265/

Comment: Hi, I have read this page and I decided to use Linux on my other laptop. I need to use MacOs for work and with VM software (like VirtualBox) the system is quite slow and laggy. Thanks again for your comment

Comment: It appears to be a problem on devices that were upgraded to Catalina.

Comment: Here is a partial fix:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1186229/324623

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I think my problem is the same as that question. Unfortunately after putting noapic I run in a different kernel panic caused by some ACPI error. Do you think that if I rollback to Mojave this will be fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to roll back MacOS is a complete reinstall. I don't have time for that now.